# How to maintain state in a Silverlight 5 application?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Silverlight. I got a login page and after the user logs in I want to maintain the username and details within the application.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Key/Value Pairs with the [**IsolatedStorageSettings class**](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/file-and-local-data/isolated-storage-%28silverlight-quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies.

1. [Silverlight Tip of the Day #18: How to Set Browser Cookies.](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/15/tip-of-the-day-18-how-to-set-browser-cookies.aspx)
2. [How to: Get and Set Cookies.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920298%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any option other than Cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Use a global context object that can be accessed from any of the Silverlight view models e.g.

```
public class ApplicationContext
{
        // Static instance of the application class.
        private static ApplicationContext _instance;

        public static ApplicationContext Instance()
        {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new ApplicationContext()
        }

        public UserDetailsCustomClass SecurityContext { get; set; }
}
```

and then it can be used anywhere within the Silverlight app e.g

```
  var submUserLogin = ApplicationContext.Instance().SecurityContext.CurrentUser.Login;
```